# Canvas inside of button with text

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have put a canvas inside of a button. The canvas displays a .png image. I want to be able to display text within the button and on top of the canvas all centralised.

HTML:

```
<div id="ST"> 
   <button id="btn1">button<canvas width="106" height="50"></canvas></button>
</div>
```

CSS (.scss):

```
#ST {
    button {
        margin-top: 8%;
        background: none;
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
            canvas {
                z-index: -1;    
            }
    }
    #btn1{
        left: 22%;
    }
}
```

This is how it currently looks:
[image]

I'm using Pesticide on Chrome so that you can see the outlines, you can see that the word "button" is pushing the canvas over. I want the word "button" directly on top of the canvas.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgzccg) of the issue.

I assume this is something I change in the CSS but I can't figure what property to set/change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide full code of your problem

Comment: @NishargShah I'm not sure what other code you want? The canvas dimensions are defined within the HTML and the .ts only writes the image to canvas. I don't see what other code would be required which would aid this.

Comment: your preview image and my local browser is different, so create pen or stackblitz

Comment: @NishargShah added.

Comment: nice i will try to solve it wait

Comment: You should position the canvas absolute (not the button itself), so that the rest of the button content can display on top of it. (And how to center that content in the button is something you should be able to research yourself, centering stuff using CSS is a topic that has been discussed more than to death already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For center you image and text, i used `flexbox` properties of CSS

I added below properties in your button for center

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
align-items: center;
```

Your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4sazcq

**EDIT 1**

I used `position` property to center it

Your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i7bozo

Comment: I wanted the word "button" to overlap the image and be in the complete center of the button

Comment: Done watch Edit